# Is there something missing in this exercise?

Tags: general-topology

Let $n \in \mathbb{N^{*}}$ and $||\cdot||$ be a $\mathbb{R^n}$ norm.
Let $F \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ be a closed set.
I have to prove that $F_{\epsilon}:={\{x\in \mathbb{R^n}:d(x,F)\leq \epsilon\}}$ is closed and
$F=\bigcap_{\epsilon > 0}F_{\epsilon}$.
$d(x,F)=inf{\{d(x,a): a \in F}\}$
To prove that $F_{\epsilon}$ is closed I did the following:

> Let $U:= \mathbb{R^n}$\ $F_{\epsilon}$ and $f:\mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f(x) = d(x,F)$ and $f$ is 1-lipschitz, therefore continuous. Observe that $U=f^{-1}(]\epsilon; \infty[)$.
> $]\epsilon; \infty[$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ and therefore $U$ is open as it's the preimage of an open set by a continuous function. Conclusion : $F_{\epsilon}$ is closed.

For the second part, I have no idea how to prove that  $F=\bigcap_{\epsilon > 0}F_{\epsilon}$. I feel like the exercise is missing something, as $F$ is just an arbitrary closed set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direction $F \subseteq \bigcap_{\epsilon > 0} F_\epsilon$ is clear, since $d(x,F)=0$ for $x \in F$.

For the reverse inclusion, show that for any $x \notin F$, there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ small enough such that $x \notin F_\epsilon$.